# Are there no command line tools for VS Web Essentials Extension?

Tags: web-essentials

We use this Visual Studio extension, but also want to use it on our CI server without checking in the generated bundled files. Are there no command line tools for this?

Wondering how the rest of the Web Essentials community is doing this.?.? Surely others have encountered this before and found a solution, no?

Comment: We too encountered the same problem. We check-in our bundled js file (and css file). We would rather have a command line tool replicate the same process in our build server, but this does the job.

Answer (score 2):

If you are at a point of setting up a CI server then the benefits of bundling built into the Visual Studio seem marginal - I would assume that you are not going to be performing deployments from VS and will be instead deploying through your CI environment.

If that is the case, I would consider turning off bundling in Web Essentials and using a command-line bundling solution such as [WebGrease](https://webgrease.codeplex.com/) or [AjaxMin](https://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/) . I [heard](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/152) that AjaxMin is what is being used by [WE and WG](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/discussions/468450) anyway.

Another approach could be to leave the WE bundling in place and attempt to use command-line WebGrease to replicate Web Essentials' bundling in your CI step:

```
wg -b -in:C:\javascript -out:bigjavascriptfile.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid it doesn't answer the actual question. In my scenario, MVC bundling is not effective. But that doesn't matter. I have it set up with WE and **want** to use WE. Its appropriateness is not at question, just whether or not it can be done, and if so, how? +1 for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [Visual Studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40) for VS 2015 if that helps, but we're still on 2013 so still looking for a better answer.